# How to configure ActiveMQ exclusive consumer with Spring boot app

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, activemq-classic

I wanted to configure exclusive consumer for ActiveMQ with Spring boot
Configuring with java is easy

```
 queue = new ActiveMQQueue("TEST.QUEUE?consumer.exclusive=true");
 consumer = session.createConsumer(queue);
```

But with Spring boot, listener is configured as below.

```
 @JmsListener(destination = "TEST.QUEUE", containerFactory = "myFactory")
 public void receiveMessage(Object message) throws Exception {
    ......
 }
```

Now, how to make this exclusive consumer? Does the below work?

```
 @JmsListener(destination = "TEST.QUEUE?consumer.exclusive=true", containerFactory = "myFactory")
 public void receiveMessage(Object message) throws Exception {
    ......
 }
```

Comment: Were you able to figure this out? I am trying to do the same thing

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's working this way.

Just set a breakpoint to the `org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQQueue` constructor and run your application in debug mode.
You will see that Spring Boot is calling
`new ActiveMQQueue("TEST.QUEUE?consumer.exclusive=true")` which corresponds to the official ActiveMQ documentation:
https://activemq.apache.org/exclusive-consumer

Moreavor you can go to the ActiveMQ admin and browse the active consumers of this queue: you will now see that the exclusive flag is set to true for your consumer.